# Compare dates in the same column with the same id

Tags: mysql

I want it to return only rows with a difference of 3 or more days, but that have the same id. I'll leave an example of the data in the database table.

| id | title | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 763 | 2023-01-11 |
| 2 | 763 | 2023-01-08 |
| 3 | 763 | 2023-01-07 |
| 4 | 545 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 545 | 2023-01-08 |
| 6 | 323 | 2023-01-07 |

The query I'm doing to return the data:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT title, 
           DATE(end) AS Regresso
    FROM AgendaSaidas 
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT title, 
           Regresso, 
           DATEDIFF(LEAD(Regresso) OVER (ORDER BY Regresso), Regresso) delta
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT title, Regresso
FROM cte2
WHERE delta >= 3 OR delta IS NULL;
```

But with this code it will only return the lines that have a difference of three days or more, as I show here what it returns:

| id | title | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 763 | 2023-01-11 |
| 2 | 763 | 2023-01-08 |
| 4 | 545 | 2023-01-01 |

But you can't remove all the other lines, because if you notice the title column has different customer ids. The result that should return was this:

| id | title | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 763 | 2023-01-11 |
| 2 | 763 | 2023-01-08 |
| 4 | 545 | 2023-01-01 |
| 5 | 545 | 2023-01-08 |
| 6 | 323 | 2023-01-07 |

You can only delete the line with id 3, because it is the only case where the date difference for the same customer is less than 3 days

Comment: Add `PARTITION BY title`. https://dbfiddle.uk/HomPcvgY PS. If `end` is DATE already then `cte1` is excess.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, I didn't remember the PARTITION BY